# Connecting to Https endpoint with custom http client not working -- javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

Tags: android, https

Please I have search through all the avilable solutions for this issue but none seems to be working for me. I am connecting to an endpoint using HTTPS and its not working. It works with higher versions of android e.g. 7.0 but isnt working on lower versions like 4.4. I tried connecting before the site was upgraded from http to https and everything seemed fine. However, now with the https, devices with lower versions of android aint connecting. Even after using a custom http client, no success.

please here is my code for the connection

here's the custom http client:

```
public static HttpClient createHttpClient()
{
    try{

    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    trustStore.load(null, null);

    SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
    sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);



    SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
    schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    schReg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

    ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schReg);

    return new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, params);
}catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "SSL catch exception");

        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

here's the implementation:

```
 public AuthorizationHttpResponse makeServiceCallJSONSSL(String url, int 
 method, JSONObject params)
{


    AuthorizationHttpResponse httpResponses = new AuthorizationHttpResponse();
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        //ssl
        HttpClient httpclient = createHttpClient();


        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            Log.e("in POST","in POST");
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(" URL");

            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                Log.e("in POST params","in POST params");

                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(params.toString(), "UTF-8"));
            }
            Log.e("url in post service",url);
            httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            //HttpClient httpclient = createHttpClient();
            //HttpPost httpResp = new HttpPost(url);


        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            Log.e("in GET","in GET");
            if (params != null) {
                Log.e("in GET params","in GET params");
                //cannot use raw json for get method
                //  String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                //       .format(params, "utf-8");
                //url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            Log.e("url in get service", url);

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);



        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        httpResponses.setResponseData(response);
        httpResponses.setResponseCode(responseCode);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Response code from server : " + responseCode + ". response gotten from service:" + response);
    return httpResponses;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting ssl handshake exceptions?

Comment: @Alex Am getting an "Unknown error during handshake"

Comment: Try to use https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html#patching Older android version 5.0 doesn't really support newer ssl protocols and ciphers.